# How to not use the first parameter of a method call and still pass JSLint?

Tags: javascript, methods, parameters, promise, jslint

I'm having to call a method with two parameters, but I'm only using the 2nd one. My code looks like this:

```
  function trapEvent(resolve, reject) {

    event_callback = function (evt) {
      evt.stopPropagation();
      if (allowDefault !== true) {
        evt.preventDefault();
      }
      cancelResolver();
      callback_promise = new Promise()
        .cancellable()
        .then(function () {
          return callback(evt);
        })
        .then(null, function (error) {
          if (!(error instanceof Promise.CancellationError)) {
            canceller();
            reject(error);
          }
        });
    };

    util.startListenTo(target, type, event_callback, useCapture);
  }

  return new Promise(trapEvent, canceller);
```

As I'm "locking" my event inside a promise, which can only be rejected or cancelled, I'm never using the `resolve` method, which JSlint rightfully complains about. However, according to [MDN es6 Promise spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), I need to provide both `resolve` and `reject` in the Promise callback method.

**Question:**
How can I make this method pass while keeping `resolve`?

Comment: When you're referencing the function that way, you'll have to use both arguments the way you're doing, and there's nothing wrong with that, just ignore jslint.

Comment: hm. any other way to do it?

Comment: you can declare as global variable

Comment: I just did a Google search and found the answer immediately.

Comment: @cookiemonster - then why not post it ?

Comment: @adeneo: Because sometimes a person just needs to go find it for themselves.

Comment: Is this question still a thing? I have a way of doing this with no change in jslint config.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to go is update your jshint.json file and configure this to be allowed.

The "unused" property is the one you are looking for. It could be tweaked to either contain the following values:

- false - don't check for unused variables
- true - "vars" + check last function param
- "vars" - skip checking unused function params
- "strict" - "vars" + check all function params

It seems to me that it currently has been set to "strict". You might want to change that to true or "vars". The latter would be useful for cases where you would not want to call the reject callback and only call the resolve method.

In case you just want to disable jshint in total for just the given line, you could do the following:

```
function trapEvent(resolve, reject) { //jshint ignore:line
```

Comment: You are right. What difference one character could make :-)

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, for jslint, what you're looking for is `unparam` -- `/*jslint unparam: true*/`

Here it is in context.  I'm guessing at globals, etc, and I'm assuming you're using the `callback_promise` somewhere later on.  Note the `unparam` at the end of the first line.

```
/*jslint white:true, sloppy:true, unparam: true */
/*global allowDefault, cancelResolver, callback, canceller, util, target, type, useCapture */

function trapEvent(resolve, reject) {
    var event_callback, callback_promise;

    event_callback = function (evt) {
      evt.stopPropagation();
      if (allowDefault !== true) {
        evt.preventDefault();
      }
      cancelResolver();
      callback_promise = new Promise()
        .cancellable()
        .then(function () {
          return callback(evt);
        })
        .then(null, function (error) {
          if (!(error instanceof Promise.CancellationError)) {
            canceller();
            reject(error);
          }
        });
    };

    util.startListenTo(target, type, event_callback, useCapture);
    // ... assuming you're using callback_promise later
}
```

There [used to be] other, slightly hipster ways of working around this, like using the `arguments` property in a function, where you could leave both parameters out of the function definition entirely, and then pull what's now `reject` out once you're in the code.

```
/*jslint white:true, sloppy:true, browser:true */
function trapEvent() {
    var reject = arguments[1];
    reject();
}

var fnTest = function () { window.alert("Used"); };
trapEvent("unused", fnTest);
```

.. but honestly, that's really hacky.  And now that I test that out, recent versions of JSLint (maybe closing the accidental loophole [starting July 3rd of last year](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSLint/commit/5b5e58feccacadcc5666c2d0128a7dac0266951c)?) don't accept it any more either, thankfully.

I recommend using `unparam`, but only in those files where you don't have control of the function signature for whatever reason, as in your use case here.